# How to move the DropdownSearch widget to the top of the screen above the keyboard in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter app where I'm using the `dropdown_search` package to implement a `multi-select dropdown`. The problem I'm facing is that when the keyboard is active, it covers the "Ok" button at the bottom of the dropdown. I want the dropdown to move to the top of the screen and show the "Ok" button above the keyboard so that the user doesn't have to manually scroll to reach it.

I've tried wrapping the `DropdownSearch` widget with a `SingleChildScrollView` but it doesn't seem to work. The dropdown still remains at the bottom of the screen, and the keyboard covers the "Ok" button.

Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dropdown_search/dropdown_search.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'MultiSelectDropDown',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'MUltiSelectDropDown'),
      initialBinding: QuestionnaireBinding(),
    );
  }
}

class QuestionnaireBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<QuestionnaireController>(() => QuestionnaireController());
  }
}

class QuestionnaireController extends GetxController
    with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
    RxList<String> choices = <String>[].obs;
    }

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final dropdownSearchTheme = ThemeData(
      colorScheme: const ColorScheme(
        primary: Color(0xFF485946),
        onPrimary: Colors.white,
        secondary: Colors.black,
        onSecondary: Colors.deepOrange,
        error: Colors.transparent,
        onError: Colors.transparent,
        background: Colors.transparent,
        onBackground: Colors.black,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        onSurface: Colors.black,
        surface: Colors.white,
      ));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const Text(
                'Let\'s start choosing',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Theme(
                data: dropdownSearchTheme,
                child: _buildDropdownSearch(
                  context,
                  Get.find<QuestionnaireController>().choices,
                  dropdownCustomBuilder: _customChoice,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildDropdownSearch(
      BuildContext context,
      RxList<String> selectedChoice,
      {Widget Function(BuildContext, List<String>)? dropdownCustomBuilder}) {
    return DropdownSearch<String>.multiSelection(
      selectedItems: selectedChoice,
      items: ["choice1", "choice2", "choice3", "choice4", "choice5", "choice6", "choice7", "choice8", "choice9", "choice10", "choice11"],
      dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps(
          dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'pickChoice',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
          )),
      dropdownBuilder: dropdownCustomBuilder,
      popupProps: PopupPropsMultiSelection.modalBottomSheet(
        modalBottomSheetProps: ModalBottomSheetProps(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
        ),
        searchFieldProps: TextFieldProps(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Search for choice',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          autofocus: true,
          focusNode: FocusNode(canRequestFocus: true),
        ),
        showSearchBox: true,
        showSelectedItems: true,
        isFilterOnline: false,
        onItemAdded: (selectedItems, addedItem) {
          selectedChoice.add(addedItem);
        },
        onItemRemoved: (selectedItems, removedItem) {
          selectedChoice.remove(removedItem);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _customChoice(BuildContext context, List<String> selectedItems) {
    final controller = Get.find<QuestionnaireController>();
    return GetBuilder<QuestionnaireController>(
      initState: (_) {},
      builder: (_) {
        if (selectedItems.isEmpty) {
          return Text("Pick a choice");
        }
        return Wrap(
          spacing: 2,
          runSpacing: -10,
          children: selectedItems.map((e) {
            return Chip(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
              label: Text(
                e.toString().trim(),
              ),
              onDeleted: () {
                selectedItems.remove(e.toString().trim());
                controller.choices.remove(e.toString().trim());
              },
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image: The screenshot of the output from above code]

I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to achieve the desired behavior of moving the dropdown to the top of the screen and showing the "Ok" button above the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can simply achieve by replacing

```
PopupPropsMultiSelection.modalBottomSheet
```

to

```
PopupPropsMultiSelection.bottomSheet
```

Comment: Great that worked, thanks, but when updating the PopupPropsMultiSelection.bottomSheet, the screen color has changed to slight pink while displaying the drop down. How can I change that to app theme background?

Comment: Okay let me check.